# Regular expression does not match

Tags: java, regex

I need to define a pattern for a string and find all matches of that in a sentence in java eclipse environment. 
This in my code:

```
public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "MD_pos ";
public static final String REGEX ="(RB_pos)?(MD_pos|VB_pos|VBD_pos|VBP_pos|VBZ_pos|VBG_pos|VBN_pos) (RP_pos)? (RB_pos)? ";

public void PatMat() {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);

    int count = 0;
    while(matcher.find()) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("found: " + count + " : "
            + matcher.start() + " - " + matcher.end());
        System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group());  
    }
}
```

Parts with `?` sign in pattern are optional so `MD_pos` should be matched. But everytime I call this method there is no result in console.

Comment: Change `(MD_pos|VB_pos|VBD_pos|VBP_pos|VBZ_pos|VBG_pos|VBN_pos)` to `(MD|VB[DPZGN]?)_pos` and make it shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to compile in `COMMENTS` mode so the spaces are ignored.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX, Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `REGEX` contains three non-optional spaces, which aren't present in the sample string you're trying to match.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer as whitespaces can be part of a regex as long as `COMMENTS` mode for the `Pattern` is on.